# Error when trying to create a webapp using CLI

Tags: azure, azure-cli, azure-webapps

I have no experience in coding, just started now.

I am trying to create a webapp using the Azure Cloud Shell, so I used the following command:

```
az webapp create --name WebAppOne --resource-group learn-64c4ca17-0293-40f6-ba23-e4581751cca0 --plan ServicePlanTest
```

Then I get the message:

Webapp 'WebAppOne' already exists. The command will use the existing app's settings.
Unable to retrieve details of the existing app 'WebAppOne'. Please check that the app is a part of the current subscription

I only have one subscription in Azure as I am still using a free account for learning purposes.

So, I decided to get a list showing the webapps that exist by using the command:

```
az webapp list --output table
```

However, the only outcome is a blank line, showing no web apps already existing. What should I try next?

Answer (score 0):

To create a web app in Azure App service, you must have a resource group and App service plan in your subscription.

To check the existing App services in your subscription

```cs
az webapp list --resource-group MyRGName
```

***Output :***
[image]

As you can see, currently I don't have any webapps created in the given Resource group

Run the below command to create an Azure Web App

```cs
az webapp create --name MyWebApp --resource-group MyRGName --plan MyAppServicePlan
```

Though I don't have any Webapps with the given name, I got the same error.

[image]

In **`Azure Portal`** => **`Azure Active Directory`** => **`App registrations`** => **`All applications`**

In search box, searched with the web app name. I can see the web app with same name is already created.

[image]

***Reason for the error***

You might have created a web app with same name long ago, but the resource got deleted from the resource group. But still, it is available in the Azure Active Directory App registrations.

- If it is created by you and you don't want to use anymore, you can delete it. If not create web app with another name.

Tried to create web app with another name.

***Create Azure App Service:***
[image]

Now I can see the created Web App List.

***List of  Azure Web Apps***
[image]